# How can I compute the distance between each pair of the sentence in a text

Tags: python, nlp

i am computing the levenshtein distance between the sentences, and now i have a text with several sentences. I don't know how to write the for loop to generate the distance between each pair of the sentence.

```
sent = ['motrin 400-600 mg every 8 hour as need for pai . ', 'the depression : continue escitalopram ; assess need to change medication as an outpatient . ', 'Blood cltures from 11-30 grow KLEBSIELLA PNEUMONIAE and 12-01 grow KLEBSIELLA PNEUMONIAE and PROTEUS MIRABILIS both sensitive to the Meropenam which she have already be receive . ']

def similarity(sent):
    feature_sim = []
    for a,b in sent:
            feature_sim[a,b] = pylev.levenshtein(a,b) 
        print (feature_sim)
```

Comment: use itertools.combinations

Comment: Or two nested for-loops

Comment: HI , do you mean like this:    
    for a in sent:
        for b in sent:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Use a pair of nested for-loops.

Simplest version:

```
for a in sent:
    for b in sent:
        ...
```

Skip identical pairs (Levenshtein distance would trivially be 0):

```
for a in sent:
    for b in sent:
        if a != b:
           ...
```

Avoid processing duplicate pairs (`a, b` is the same as `b, a`):

```
for i in range(0, len(sent)):
    for j in range(i+1, len(sent)):
        # a = sent[i], b = sent[j]
        ...
```

> Problem: `feature_sim` is a **list**, which can only be indexed by integers, not strings or any other types.

Use a **dictionary** instead:

```
feature_sim = {}
for i in range(0, len(sent)):
    for j in range(i+1, len(sent)):
        feature_sim[(sent[i], sent[j])] = pylev.levenshtein(sent[i], sent[j])
```